# Convert regex from gskinner to PHP

Tags: php, regex

I know that I'd likely hear "Don't parse HTML with regex", so let me say that this question is just academic at this point because I actually solved my problem using the DOM, but on my road to a solution, I ran across this pattern that works on the [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) website, but I can't figure out how to make it work in PHP `preg_match()`.

`(?<=href\=")[^]+?(?=")`

I think that the `[^]` is causing the problem, but I'm not certain what to do about it.

What it is intended to do is pull the substring from between the quotes of an href. (One would expect it to be a web-address or at least part of one.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^]` is a difficult construct. Basically it is an empty negated character class. But what should it match? That depends on the implementation. Some languages are interpreting it as negation of nothing, so it will match every character, that is what gskinner (means ActionScript 3) seems to be doing.

I would never use this, because it is ambiguous.

The most readable way is to use `.`, the meta character that matches every character (without newlines), if newlines are also wanted, just add the modifier `s` that enables the dotall mode, this would be exactly what you wanted to achieve with `[^]`.

A workaround that is sometimes used is to use a character class something like this `[\s\S]` or `[\w\W]`. Those will also match every character (including newlines), because they are matching some predefined character class and their negation.